# Understanding piece of code written in PHP using Zend framework

Tags: java, php, zend-framework, encoding, sha256

I am java developer and I am trying to use one WEB Service API ([ticketutils](http://api.ticketutils.net/Home/GettingStarted)) where they have explained two examples first one with `PHP` and second one with `C#`. Unfortunately I am not able to get any of them. I have mentioned PHP example below.

```
 public function GenerateSignature($Secret,$PathAndQuery)
     {
       return base64_encode(\Zend_Crypt_Hmac::compute($Secret, 'sha256',
       $PathAndQuery, \Zend_Crypt_Hmac::BINARY));
     }
```

Can anyone please explain me how can I achieve the same with Java code? I have tried below code but it seems it's not generating proper outcome.

```
public static String generateSignature(String secrete, String pathAndQuery){
        String encoded = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(secrete.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            md.update(pathAndQuery.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] digest = md.digest();
            encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encoded;
    }
```

**NOTE :** I have used Java-8 for while writing above code.

Comment: I think from c# to java maybe easier..

Comment: @aaronxxx, you can see the C# method as well (refer the link) and help me if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash a Secret keyword with sha256..Then use the keyword to encode anything in Base64..

Have a look at 
http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#java

Not exactly what you are looking for but you can turn the process into a function which takes two arguments and returns the Base64 value..

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class ApiSecurityExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
     String secret = "secret";
     String message = "Message";

     Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
     SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
     sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

     String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
     System.out.println(hash);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error");
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Keep helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The Java API for message digests is very similar to the C# one. Please follow this example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Comment: thanks for you time but I have used the same example in above my method. If you can find different, please can you suggest for the same?